# Create a filter which show the last 12 hours data power bi

Tags: powerbi, analytics, reporting, powerbi-desktop

I want to create a filter in power bi which first shows the data of the last 12 hours and the second the history of the data based on my datetime field named "open_time".

For example :

[image: picture of the filter]

When I click on "now", I want to display the data of the last 12 hours based on open_time field in a table visualization and when o click on history, I have a date filter where I can choose one date and one hour.

Sorry for my English, hope you understand my problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create an unconnected table with labels ("Now", "Historic") to use as a slicer.

Then we can create measuers

```
CheckTime = 
var __selectedType = SELECTEDVALUE(disconnected[tagList])
var __DateForFilter = if( __selectedType = "a", TODAY() + TIME(HOUR(NOW()) - 4, MINUTE(NOW()), SECOND(NOW()))  , NOW())
return
calculate( SUM(DateTimeTab[val] ), FILTER(ALL(DateTimeTab), DateTimeTab[Data] >= __DateForFilter ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I forget to say that i have a datetime field in my table named : open_time. So I want that the filter « now and historic » based on that open_time field.